# How can I stop the "Favorites" icon from constantly reappearing on my desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, favorites

I accidentally dragged the "favorites" link to my desktop once, and now it constantly reappears, despite repeated attempts at nuking it. How can I prevent it from reappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on it next time it appears, and change its location.

On the "Location" tab, change it to `C:\Users\<username>\Favorites`.

Then if there's still a shortcut on the desktop, delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting it, drag it somewhere else. That way, it won't get recreated there next time you make a favorite.

Basically, when you put it on your desktop, it recorded that as the path for your favorites.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the icon and select Properties
2. Go to the Location tab and click "Restore Default"
3. Click Apply, then OK